# SELECT record which contains some words not the whole word

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

Is there a way to run a query to select only the records that contains few words not the whole word?

For example, In mysql table I have records with these codes

```
productColumn
F2018%First%Shirt%Blue&UniqueID, 
F2018%Third%Shirt%Yellow&UniqueID, 
F2018%Second%Shirt%Green&UniqueID.
```

**I would like to select the records that contains only "F2018" & "Blue".**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE productColumn CONTAINS 'F2018%Second%Shirt%Blue&UniqueID';
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select * 
from mytable 
where productcolumn like '%F2018%' and productcolumn like '%Blue%'
```

Or, if you know in advance the sequence of the two search terms in the string:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where productcolumn like '%F2018%Blue%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Like and wildcards

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE productColomn LIKE '%F2018%' AND productColumn LIKE '%Blue%';
```

note this is case insensitive so it will match Blue and blue and bluE